# Docusign REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to update the company name of the user using the REST service call https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/user/{userId}/profile

For any 'Active' user, it works well but for the 'ActivationSent' user, it gives me Status Code = 400 - Bad Request message. Has someone came across this issue?

Thanks,
Vipul

Comment: I have been unable to test this but perhaps for 'activationsent' users (aka NOT active users), have you tried a delete + re-create as an alternative/workaround?

Comment: Thanks for replying Luis. I haven't yet as for just one field value update, it seems to be an overkill. I have about 1500 such users - isn't there another way to do it?

Comment: So if they all are in "activationSent" status that means none of them have verified their email to create their account.  In other words, they have not done anything with DocuSign yet.  If that's the case, they aren't really active right? As such, it sounds like the API does not let you update inactive users so Luis' solution might be the best way to move forward.  Do you know why none of the 1500 people have activated their accounts?